# Move around GoogleMap on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

I'm creating a store locator with a list of stores and their details, plus each store has a View on Map button which allows you to move to the correspondent marker and displays an `infowindow`, like on this website http://www.poundland.co.uk/store-finder/searchResults/

I've got this code to create markers:

```
function createMarker(point, name, address, urladdress, locationNumber,id) {

            var image = {
                url: "/i/markers/MapIcon.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(48, 55),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(24, 0)
            };

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: map,
                /*shadow: shadow,*/
                icon: image,
                title: address,
               // id:id
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: name + '<br>' + address + '<br>' + '<a target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=from:' + homeSpatialInfo.fromAddress + '+to:' + urladdress + '">Directions</a>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                map.setZoom(16);
            });

            return marker;
        }
```

I'm giving each button the ID of the store it is associated with it

```
<div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 5px;">
  <asp:Button ID="viewStoreBtn-133"class="btn btn-default btn-sm viewStoreBtn" runat="server" Text="view on map" style="border-radius: 10px;"/>view on map
</div>
```

After that I guess I will have to add an `onclick` event listener but I'm not sure what to write in the `onclick` function (as I'm very new to this).

Comment: Please also tag [tag:asp.net] for this kind of questions and tell which language you are using, VB or C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `google.maps.event.addListener` for `click`. This is my example and i think it will be usefull for you.

In initMap add these codes:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event);
});

function placeMarker(event) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    console.log(event.latLng);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    geocoder.geocode({'location': event.latLng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                map.setZoom(11);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: event.latLng,
                  map: map
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    if (infowindow) {
                        infowindow.close();
                    }
                    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + results[0].name + '</strong><br>' +
                                           '<br>' +
                                           results[0].formatted_address + '</div>');
                  console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
                  console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                  console.log(results[0].name + results[0].formatted_address + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                  infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            } else {
            window.alert('No results found');
          } 
        } else {
          window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

if you have marker you can just use pan function to move view area.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.panTo(this.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. Am I right in thinking that this code displays info window for a marker when it is clicked?

Comment: If so, I have already got code that does that (sorry, should have made this clear in the question!) - and now I would like to move to the correspondent marker when you click a View Store button.

Comment: @OksanaKing Added move function.

Comment: I've added a function `$('.viewStoreBtn').click(function () {
        var storeID = this.id.split("-")[1];
        var markerStore = ArrayMarkers[storeID];
        map.setZoom(16);
        map.panTo(markerStore.getPosition());
           
        google.maps.event.addListener($('.viewStoreBtn'), 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, markerStore);
        });`